# Как сделать авторизацию sudo по ssh-ключу?

Tags: linux, debian, ssh, sudo, ssh-key

Суть вот в чем:

- Сделал юзера, дал ему sudo, запретил парольную авторизацию, запретил
  логин root
- Каждый раз при запросе sudo спрашивает пароль
- Если пароль
  убрать или сделать ненадежным (сейчас более 20 символов), это, как
  говорят, дырка, но а вообще, зачем козе баян, и зачем при отказе от
  пароля при авторизации на сервере теперь мне нужно вводить пароль для
  подтверждения прав рута? Логика неконсистентная более чем полностью.

Должно быть что-то одно:

- Или отказ от авторизации по паролям и авторизация только по ключу —
  мера достаточная, и root убирать никуда не надо
- Или необходимо сделать
  консистентную авторизацию, т.е. sudo должно спрашивать не пароль у
  пользователя, а RSA ключ у ssh-клиента.

Есть еще вариант убрать полностью пароль у sudo, но тогда какой вообще в нем смысл? Это по сути будет тот же root со ступенькой (необходимость каждый чих вводить через sudo).

Я решил пойти вторым путем и сделать авторизацию через ssh-ключи, и использовать pam_ssh_agent_auth.
Делал согласно этой инструкции:
http://mike.depalatis.net/ssh-agent-for-sudo-authentication-with-a-passwordless-account.html

Результат нулевой - все равно требует пароль. Есть немаленькая вероятность, что я где-то накосячил, ибо инструкция совершенно зажевана в конце - мне не совсем понятно что там и как.

Какие мысли?

Answer (score 6):

Чтобы в *sudo* не требовался пароль, добавьте нужную строку в файл (новый или существующий) в `/etc/sudoers.d`. Как правило, на каждую учетку создается свой файл с настройками. (Вместо `username` - ваше имя пользователя.)

```
echo "username ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers.d/username
```

> авторизация только по ключу мера достаточная и root убирать никуда не надо

Авторизация по ключу обычно более надёжна, чем по паролю. Авторизацию по паролю для root вообще желательно запретить.

> зачем при отказе от пароля при авторизации на сервере теперь мне нужно вводить пароль для подтверждения прав рута? Логика неконсистентная более чем полностью.

Программы *ssh(d)* и *sudo* связаны между собой чуть более, чем никак. Одной нет никакого дела до того, как настроена авторизация в другой.

Comment: > echo "username ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers.d/username
Я выше написал что не хотел бы этого делать, т/к это уничножает пользу от запрета рут на сервере
> Авторизацию по паролю для root вообще желательно запретить.
У меня в самом начале указано что парольная авторизация полностью запрещена!

Comment: > Программы ssh(d) и sudo связаны между собой чуть более, чем никак. Одной нет никакого дела до того, как настроена авторизация в другой.

Вопрос не к программам, а к разработчикам и специалистам по безопасности. Ничего не мешает сделать или отдельные ключи для sudo  или использовать ключи SSH-клиента, что собственно и делает указанный PAM модуль. Почему в многочисленных инструкциях по настройке и безопасности сохраняется эта неконсистентность во в чем вопрос. Пароль априори не может быть безопаснее ключа он не может быть сильно длинным и сложным, т/к требуется его ввод руками).

Comment: @Unicom а, понял вас. Я думал, нужны объяснения для довольно базовых вещей, но вроде бы вы уже в этом хорошо разбираетесь. `Каждый раз при запросе sudo спрашивает пароль` - не помню где, но точно где-то настраивается время, в течение которого можно не спрашивать повторно.

Comment: ssh-add -t 600 - перегенерирует секретный ключ и установит время его "кэша" 10 минут (600 секунд). Это лучше чем каждый раз вводить, однако все же не решение.

Answer (score 5):

> зачем при отказе от пароля при авторизации на сервере теперь мне нужно вводить пароль для подтверждения прав рута?

программа *sudo* предназначена для выполнения (любых или указанных) команд от имени другого указанного пользователя (по умолчанию — пользователя root). по умолчанию запрашивается пароль текущего пользователя, **для подтверждения, что программу *sudo* запустил именно этот пользователь** (а не для «подтверждения прав рута»).

кстати, данное поведение может быть переопределено: см. описание флагов [rootpw, targetpw и runaspw](http://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.13/sudoers.man.html) в `man 5 sudoers`.

> Должно быть что-то одно:
>   - Или отказ от авторизации по паролям и авторизация только по ключу мера достаточная и root убирать никуда не надо
>   - Или необходимо сделать консистентную авторизацию, т/е sudo должно спрашивать не пароль у пользователя, а RSA ключ у ssh клиента.

запрос пароля на удалённом сервере, куда пользователь получает доступ только по ключу, может послужить дополнительным барьером для случаев [компрометации](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%28%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F%29) секретного ключа или машины пользователя.

> Есть еще вариант убрать полностью пароль у sudo но тогда какой вообще в нем смысл? Это по сути будет тот же root со ступенькой (необходимость каждый чих вводить через sudo)

даже если пользователь, которому разрешено использовать программу *sudo*, всего один, и даже если ему разрешено выполнять любые команды от имени любого пользователя, автоматическое логирование всех запусков программы *sudo* может оказать существенную помощь при устранении ситуации «что-то пошло не так».

если же таких пользователей несколько, логирование ещё более полезно.

> Делал согласно этой инструкции

вероятно, лучше использовать уже [готовый пакет](https://packages.debian.org/experimental/libpam-ssh-agent-auth). если вы используете стабильный выпуск (*jessie*, версия 8) или новее, в репозиториях есть необходимые зависимости. если более старый выпуск, возможно, потребуется пересборка пакета с указанием более старых версий зависимостей. в любом случае, лучше использовать пакет (пусть даже пересобранный), чем загрязнять систему не контролируемыми пакетным менеджером программами.

> Какие мысли?

pam-аутентификация по ключу, с моей точки зрения, не сможет послужить полноценной заменой вводу пароля в случае компрометации секретного ключа или машины пользователя. разве что частично: если для аутентификации используется *другой* ключ (не тот же, что и для доступа по *ssh*), защищённый кодовой фразой.

---

**пару слов по поводу [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/496484/178576) от [Pavel Mayorov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178779/pavel-mayorov)**

> На сервере никто не работает через ssh, его только администрируют. А потому обычный пользователь и не нужен.

ситуация, когда «пользователь» у сервера всего один — встречается, думаю, довольно часто.

но и ситуация, когда «пользователей» больше одного — тоже далеко не редкость.

и вряд ли редкостью можно назвать ситуацию, когда пользователи выполняют именно пользовательские задачи, не связанные с администрированием. та же веб-разработка, например. для которой может потребоваться выполнение *некоторых* административных задач (например, конфигурирование и управление http-сервером), в чём программа *sudo*, несомненно, способна послужить незаменимым подспорьем.

> За веб-разработку на сервере надо бить по рукам. Для этой цели виртуалки есть.

да, «сервер» вполне может быть и виртуальной машиной. способы же использования машины (как виртуальной, так и «железной», как выполняющей роль «сервера», так и выполняющей любую иную роль), вероятно, определяет её владелец, а не мы с вами.

к тому же веб-разработка была приведена лишь в качестве иллюстрации. неплохим семейством иллюстраций может быть использование сервера(-ов) для ресурсоёмких задач: компиляции, сборки пакетов, рендеринга, конвертации видео, data-mining-а, той же виртуализации и т.д. и т.п.

---

**обновление по поводу «неработоспособности» пакета**

как написано в `man pam_ssh_agent_auth` (страница идёт в комплекте с пакетом), надо добавить в `/etc/pam.d/sudo` строку примерно такого содержания:

```
auth sufficient pam_ssh_agent_auth.so file=/etc/security/authorized_keys
```

она должна идти **до** строк с *include*-ами.

в указанный файл с ключами `/etc/security/authorized_keys` надо добавить тот публичный ключ, по которому и будет происходить pam-аутентификация. в принципе, расположение этого файла — произвольное, и может быть даже привязано к домашнему каталогу пользователя: см. секцию примеров в упомянутой man-странице.

перед использованием такой аутентификации, вероятно, лучше завершить все процессы пользователя и перелогиниться.

при подключении надо, естественно, пропускать соединение с вашим *ssh-agent*-ом с «сервера». либо с помощью соответствующей опции в `~/.ssh/config`, либо с помощью опции `-A` программы *ssh*.

если всё перечисленное не помогает, добавьте в конце той же строки (в файле `/etc/pam.d/sudo`) директиву *debug*. тогда в `/var/log/auth.log` будет более подробное описание.

Comment: Да, у меня ключ защищен фразой, фразу хранит связка ключей, это довольно удобно и безопасно. А если стукнут по голове кирпичем и заберут ноутбук, не будет уже все равно, что ключ скомпрометирован.

Comment: Да, про ситуацию с вебразработчиками я конечно не подумал, т/к моя ситуация простая как доска - я один и один хожу на сервер. Соответственно именно в моем случае видимо sudo это более раздражающий фактор, чем помощь в защите.

Comment: >>лучше использовать уже готовый пакет. если вы используете стабильный выпуск (jessie, версия 8)
Да все обыскал нашел лишь несколько инструкций одна старше другой , и в одном мануале репозиторий через  убунтовский лаунчпад. Даже не подумал, что дебиан уже включил модуль в пакет. В любом случае откуда бы не был взят пакет, настроить его все равно не получилось. Все равно судо требовало пароль.

Comment: Там действительно есть ситуации, когда это надо. А так конечно лучше всех куда-нибудь в... docker :)

Comment: В принципе все понятно. Однако 2 блиц вопроса:
1) Ладно, в консоль ходить рутом - это все таки спорный вопрос, однако понятно зачем это делать. Зачем ходить рутом по sftp - это не понятно. Можно ли тогда юзеру закрыть консоль и оставить только работу с файлами по sftp (а в консоль я раз в месяц и рутом схожу) ?
2) В чем опасность использования в качестве такого юзера www-data?  Если опасность конечно не высосана из пальца, т/к я видел доводы как против (обычно: да вы что, нельзя!), так и за в виде мануалов как разрешить этому юзеру логиниться и sftp.

Comment: @Unicom, вы задали два новых вопроса. лучше использовать для этого (дважды) кнопку «задать вопрос» в правом верхнем углу страницы. естественно, перед публикацией вопросов стоит придать им больше конкретики и однозначности, чтобы они не попали в категорию «ответ зависит лишь от мнения».

Comment: Это тогда мне придется описывать всю ситуацию заново. Ок never mind ;)

Comment: @Unicom, то, что вы спросили в комментарии, вполне возможно, уже обсуждалось здесь (вероятно, и не раз), и, на мой взгляд, никак не связано с текущим вопросом. впрочем, ничто не мешает привести в вопросе ссылку на другой вопрос.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496692/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-www-data-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-sftp

Answer (score 4):

Если вам требуется получение рут-доступа по ключу - так разрешите его по ключу. Создайте отдельный ключ ssh, защитите его паролем (опционально) и разрешите руту входить по этому ключу.

Программа `sudo` больше предназначена для локальных пользователей, а не для удаленных. На сервере `sudo` вообще не требуется.

---

Возможно, для утверждения *"на сервере `sudo` вообще не требуется"* нужно дополнительное обоснование, ведь оно идет вразрез со стандартной рекомендацией *"не сидите под рутом!"*. Поясняю.

Рут - это пользователь, который выполняет администрирование компьютера. При локальной работе, пользователь не все время занят администрированием своего компьютера - он еще за ним иногда работает :) Отсюда и требование разделения - работать под одним пользователем, администрировать - под рутом. А отсюда - и `sudo`, `su`...

На сервере никто не работает через ssh, его только администрируют. А потому обычный пользователь и не нужен.

Comment: Интересная точка зрения, логичная, но нигде подобного объяснения я еще не встречал. Однако встречал кучу мануалов как убрать root именно с сервера (с этого начинаются все даже самые краткие инструкции по безопасности). Я тоже не вижу разницы между логином под рутом и логином под другим юзером с sudo без пароля. Однако миллионы мух не могут видимо ошибаться. Да и зачем было писать тот модуль, что я привел, как раз именно для авторизации sudo через ключ от SSH-клиента, ведь это можно использовать исключительно на сервере.

Comment: `root` с сервера в инструкциях убирают потому что когда эти инструкции писались впервые, ssh-ключей еще не изобрели :) Модуль же нужен для редких случаев удаленного рабочего места или в корпоративных сетях с аудитом всего на свете.

Comment: Хотите сказать что с тех пор инструкции просто бездумно переписывают и даже безопасникам не приходит в голову избавиться от такого оверкилла?

Comment: @Unicom бездумное переписывание инструкций - это вообще любимое занятие айтишников :) В любой области, надо раз сто-двести бездумно что-нибудь переписать прежде чем придет понимание что вообще происходит. Иногда этим "чем-нибудь" становится инструкция...

Comment: Кстати в поддержку вашей теории могу сказать, что в серверном Debian 8 по умолчанию никакого sudo вроде как не идет (я смотрел в двух образах на VPS от двух разных хостингах), и root не отключен.
Это меня натолкнуло на сомнения, но я действительно не видел ни одной инструкции где одним из первых пунктов не шло бы отключите нафиг рут, сконфигурируйте доступ по ключам, отключите пароли. Между тем следует из нашей беседы, что это вообще взаимоисключающие пункты

Comment: @Unicom пункт "отключите пароли" отключает их в ssh, а не на сервере целиком - так что в этих пунктах нет ничего взаимоисключающего. Просто overkill.

Comment: да, но отключив  авторизацию у рута, и не создав еще одного судо юзера на сервер больше не попадешь. Поэтому конечно в инструкциях есть и создание юзера и как его в судо группу добавить. Я же говорю, что пункты инструкций противоречивы, если следовать вашей логике и sudo реально не нужно на сервере. Либо пытаются покрыть одной инструкцией все варианты настройки, что создает этот самый оверкилл

Comment: Несколько девелоперов на одном сервере работают через ssh.