# В чем опасность использования пользователя www-data для доступа по SFTP?

Tags: debian, ssh, безопасность, permissions, sftp

Дано:
Debian 8, Вебсервер, используется nginx, php-fpm, mariadb, redis, авторизация SSH настроена только по ключам.
По сути, на сервере только я и мои сайты.

В чем опасность разблокировки юзера www-data для доступа по SFTP? По этому поводу слышал как мнения за - это действительно проще, не нужно мудрить с правами, и не нужно с помощью umask повышать права для группы www-data, если мы будем использовать другого юзера из этой группы. Что хорошо.

И высказывания против, мол, дескать, это ухудшает безопасность, и вообще нельзя, т.к. это системный юзер и не зря ему запретили консоль и внешний доступ.

Вот, скажем, ман как его разблокировать и начать использовать: 
https://easyengine.io/tutorials/linux/setup-sftp/

Хочется узнать конкретные примеры, почему это плохо, т.к. почему это хорошо, я и так знаю.

Answer (score 1):

> Вот, скажем, ман как его разблокировать и начать использовать

на мой взгляд, это действительно *вредная* инструкция. если исходить из того, что требуется монтировать домашний каталог этого пользователя по ssh с аутентификацией по ключу (с помощью *sshfs*, *winscp* и тому подобного).

ведь для такого доступа не требуется ни устанавливать пароль пользователю, ни разрешать ему использование интерактивной оболочки.

достаточно лишь <s>в качестве оболочки указать ему `/usr/bin/scponly` (входит в пакет *scponly*)</s> и в домашнем каталоге пользователя создать каталог `.ssh`, а в нём — файл `authorized_keys` с нужными публичными ключами.

<s>поменять оболочку можно с помощью программы *chsh*. например:</s>

```
$ sudo chsh -s /usr/bin/scponly www-data
```

домашний каталог пользователя можно узнать командой `getent passwd пользователь`. пример:

```
$ getent passwd www-data 
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/bin/scponly
```

шестое поле (`/var/www`) — это и есть домашний каталог. в нём и надо создать каталог `.ssh` с файлом `authorized_keys` и задать им нужную принадлежность и права (обратите внимание, что владельцу в данном случае не нужен и даже излишен доступ на запись):

```
$ sudo mkdir /var/www/.ssh
$ cat файл.с.публичным.ключом | sudo tee -a /var/www/.ssh/authorized_keys
$ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/.ssh
$ sudo chmod -R u-w,go= /var/www/.ssh
```

---

ещё по поводу небезопасности инструкций, подобных приведённой в вопросе: в них обычно опускается необходимость ограничения доступа к каталогу `.ssh` по протоколу *http*. этого можно добиться, конечно, с помощью соответствующих инструкций в конфигурации http-сервера (или даже с помощью *.htaccess* в случае, если это *apache*), но более предпочтительным, на мой взгляд, является **неиспользование** `/var/www` в качестве *docroot*-а для какого-либо сервера: *docroot*-ы лучше расположить **глубже** в этом же каталоге.

---

к слову, чтобы с помощью этого пользователя нельзя было примонтировать произвольный каталог (а только его домашний), можно воспользоваться советом из ответа к этому вопросу: [Запрет листинга корневого каталога при подключении SFTP (SSH File Transfer)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/424663/178576)

---

**обновление по поводу scponly**

этот пакет [исключили из репозиториев](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=650590) ввиду дублирования встроенной в *openssh-server* функциональности. эта функциональность описана в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424719/178576), ссылка на который приведена выше. обратите внимание на дополнение по поводу домашнего каталога.

Comment: Файлы сайтов находятся /var/www/sitename.com/htdocs/

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36179/discussion-between-alexander-barakin-and-unicom).